# Как импортировать посты в WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

Нужно импортировать очень много записей в кастомный пост тайп. Погуглил вопрос, наткнулся на плагин All import. Удобный плагин, но платный, а провести импорт нужно всего раз, в будущем такой необходимости не будет.

Пожалуйста, подскажите, какие есть еще инструменты/плагины/варианты импортировать в свой пост тайп посты?

Comment: Куча бесплатных плагинов в оф каталоге. Включая WP All Import

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл плагин: WP Import Export Lite. Он бесплатно поддерживает функционал, который платно поддерживает WP ALl Import.